# RxJS Method to Help Reduce Data Shifting on Page Several Times in Angular App?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I am using observables in my Angular 2 app. In this one particular case I am subscribing to some data that is being filtered (based on user selections). The functionality is working, however, the experience is slightly "herky-jerky" in that the tabular display shifts a couple of times. Also, I notice that the console.log message I have in the main filter function call repeats several times in the console.

So, all that is to say, I'm wondering if there's an RxJS method I can add, right before I subscribe, to reduce the number of times the screen shifts with data being filtered. This is what my code looks like:

```
private processType(name: string, value: any, body)
{
    if (this.body[name] && !value) {
            delete this.body[name];
        } else {
            this.body[name] = { $in: value };
        }
}

private onFilterReceived(value: any, type: string, body, pn_lang_e, pn_lang_s, pn_disc_e, pn_disc_s)
{
    if (type === 'lan')
    {
        this.processType('languages.primary', value, body);
    } if (type === 'dis')
    {
        this.processType('services.service', value, body);
    } 
    console.log('filters triggering...');
    this.dataService.getBySelections(
        this.page - 1, this.pagesize, this.body, this.sort, this.pn_lang_e, this.pn_lang_s, this.pn_disc_e, this.pn_disc_s)
        .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
            this.records = resRecordsData;
            console.log('filter call arriving...');
            this.data = resRecordsData.data;
            if (this.filter === undefined)
            {
                this.data = resRecordsData.data;
            } else
            this.data.sort(this.filter);
        },
        responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);

    console.log(this.router.url);
}
```

By the way, the console.log I see being triggered multiple times in the console is this one:

```
console.log('filter call arriving...');
```

For further information, onFilterReceived() gets triggered when a user makes a filter selection and/or when the component loads. And getBySelection() is an API call to a MongoDB/Node backend. We are making use of a Mongo/Mongoose feature where we can pass filter values as key/value pairs right in the body of the API call.

Does this seem like a behavior that can be helped by adding RxJS chain-able method? Or is this behavior (specifically the data shifting several times and the multiple triggering of the above console.log statement) unrelated to this? Just trying to understand RxJs a little more, to see if it can help in situations like this.

UPDATE: Upon a commenter's suggestion, I added a console.log statement immediately before the dataService API call (and updated my code here), and can confirm that triggers multiple times, even on initial component load. Additional info: I am initializing my various filters, so that they're available for users.

UPDATE 2: Re: another comment/question, the way this Mongoose feature works, I am passing an array for each filter element, in the body of the request. Would that be related to what's causing this? Here's an example of the one arrays passed, related to language. This basically says, give me all results matching these three array values, when applied to the "language.primary" property.

```
$in:["English", "Spanish", "Mandarin"]
```

The actual network call for this particular filter element, that I can see in my Chrome network tab, is this:

```
languages.primary:{$in: ["English", "Spanish", "Mandarin"]}
```

So, again, one of these goes out in the payload for each filter element. And it goes out on every call.

UPDATE 3:

On initial component load I see about 25 network requests going out. The payload of the last request looks like this (the arrays contain data because on initial load I am passing all possible values for each filter -- and from there the user can make selections to edit these values passed):

```
languages.primary : {$in: ["English", "Spanish", "Mandarin"]} 
services.service : {$in: ["service1", "service2", "service3"]} 
services.flags.action : {$in: ["flag1", "flag2", "flag3",…]}
```

UPDATE 4: To help provide context on my filtering here, please see this related question I've just posted:
[A More Elegant Way to Handle Filtering Values in Angular App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45869108/a-more-elegant-way-to-handle-filtering-values-in-angular-app)

Comment: when and how is `onFilterReceived()` triggered? Does `getBySelection()` fetch data from a remote server?

Comment: onFilterReceived() gets triggered when a user makes a filter selection and/or when the component loads. And, yes, getBySelection() is an API call to a MongoDB/Node backend. We are making use of a Mongo/Mongoose feature where we can pass filter values as key/value pairs right in the body of the API call.

Comment: Is the `console.log()` being triggered multiple times at each `onFilterReceived()` execution? or once per execution?

Comment: It appears to be multiple times per execution.

Comment: Can you put a console.log in onFilterReceived function, to check if is called multiple times? Also can you add implementation of this.dataService.getBySelections, it is possible that you are sending result multiple times while making API call.

Comment: Can you describe where exactly you'd like me to place an additional console.log statement? The one I have already is on the onFilterReceived() function.

Comment: just before you make dataService call.

Comment: If `onFilterReceived` is called only once when a filter value changes, then it should only execute the `dataService` call one time per filter change and you should see it log only once. (Unless the service is returning multiple datasets?) Bottom line ... it should be working as you want (only executed one time per selection) ... so if it is not there is something wrong somewhere else and throwing more operators on it may not help. Any way you can demonstrate with a Plunker?

Comment: After adding the suggested console.log statement, I can confirm it's triggering multiple times. Even on initial component load, that new console.log statement triggers 12 times.

Comment: Not familiar with using Plunkr yet. Otherwise I'd be happy to.

Comment: Can you add your HTML code and how you are using onFilterReceived?

Comment: Re: DeborahK's comment/question, the way this Mongoose feature works, I am passing an array for each filter element, in the body of the request. Would that be related to what's causing this? Here's an example of the one arrays passed, related to language. This basically says, give me all results matching these three array values, when applied to the "language.primary" property.

$in:["English", "Spanish", "Mandarin"]

I added this and additional code above.

Comment: @Muirik open the browser console and look at network requests. Then trigger `onFilterChange` once (make sure it's once) and see how many requests are going over the network

Comment: Regarding Plunker ... go here: https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue Select `New | Angular` from the New dropdown and then you are set to add any code you need to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: Additional network request info added above.