# A More Elegant Way to Handle Filtering Values in Angular App

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular, typescript, mongoose

I am running into some issues with data in a tabular display reloading several times in my Angular 2 app. I'm thinking the main issue with that is related to the fact that, upon initial component loading, I am sending data for a series of filters along as network requests.

Basically we're making use of a Mongo/Mongoose feature that lets us pass key/value pairs in the object body of a post request, which then returns a filtered dataset based on those passed-in values. This code looks like this:

```
private processType(name: string, value: any, body)
{
    if (this.body[name] && !value) {
            delete this.body[name];
        } else {
            this.body[name] = { $in: value };
        }
}
```

All that's working as expected. However, what feels less than ideal in my current implementation is that on initial component load I am passing an array of all possible values for each of those filters. And from there a user can change what's passed and filtered-on via a UI filter list. I am passing the entire array of possible values for each filter on initial component load, because if I pass in an empty array NOTHING will match. However, it seems like there should be a better way to handle my initial request.

I'd ideally like my initial request to be, effectively, "don't initially filter on anything", rather than "filter initially on everything", as I'm doing now. I've done it this way for now, because it's a little tricky to handle both the condition on initial load, AND in a situation where a user removes a filter, or all filters. Right now, in either of those scenarios, I'm just passing in the array of all possible values again. What I have works, but it doesn't seem as elegant as it could be. Since this is all being passed as an object in the body of the post request, is there a way I could just delete the object rather than passing an object with arrays of all values?

This is what the rest of my relevant code looks like:

```
public initLanguageFilterOptions(): void
{
    this.languageFilterOptions = new FilterOptions([
        { value: 'English', toString: () => 'English' },
        { value: 'Spanish', toString: () => 'Spanish' },
        { value: 'Mandarin', toString: () => 'Mandarin' }
    ]);

    let arr = [];

    // Update array when filter selection is made
    arr.push(this.languageFilterOptions.addEventListener(FilterOptions.CHANGE_EVENT, () => this.sendLangSelections(true)));

    // Update array when filter options are loaded from URL parameters
    arr.push(this.languageFilterOptions.addEventListener(FilterOptions.URL_LOAD_EVENT, () => this.sendLangSelections(true)));

    // Clean up after component is no longer used
    this.addEventListener('ngOnDestroy', function ()
    {
        arr.forEach(s => s()); // Remove all listeners
        return true;
    }.bind(this));

}

/**
* Handles the emitting of the selected values to the API
*/
private sendLangSelections(languageFilterOptions) {
    const origLangArray = ['English', 'Spanish', 'Mandarin'];
    if (languageFilterOptions)
        {
            let selectionsArray = this.languageFilterOptions.selection;
            let values = selectionsArray.map((a) => { return a.value; });
            if (values && values.length > 0)
                {
                    this.sendLanguage.emit(values);
                }
            else if (values && values.length < 1)
                {
                    this.sendLanguage.emit(origLangArray);
                }
        }
}
```

This is what my API call to our Mongo/Mongoose/Node backend looks like:

```
// A POST request to work with observables
public obsPost(strReq, page, pagesize, body, sort?) {
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
    return this.http.post
    (`${API.URL}/${API.VER}${strReq}?apikey=${API.KEY}&page=${page}&pagesize=${pagesize}`,
    body, options)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .catch(this.filterErrorHandler);
}
    filterErrorHandler(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work, it's a matter of adding some more conditional logic to when a value gets passed via `{ $in: value }`. Since the errors that were popping up were because of formatting issues with `{ $in: value }`, the key was to make sure this is triggered only when there is a value to be passed.

So, in the end, to get this to work - without having to pass in an array of all possible values, which was not an elegant nor performant solution - I changed this:

```
private processType(name: string, value: any, body)
{
    if (this.body[name] && !value) {
            delete this.body[name];
        } else {
            this.body[name] = { $in: value };
        }
}
```

... to this:

```
private processType(name: string, value: any, body)
{
    if (this.body[name] && !value || this.body[name] && value.length < 1) {
            delete this.body[name];
        } else if (value) {
            this.body[name] = { $in: value };
        }
}
```

What this does is basically ensure that an array of at least one value is available when the { $in: value } is triggered.

The only other change necessary was the one involving what gets emitted when a user has de-selected all values. I handled that, this way:

```
private sendLangSelections(languageFilterOptions) {
    const origLangArray = ['English', 'Spanish', 'Mandarin'];
    if (languageFilterOptions)
        {
            let selectionsArray = this.languageFilterOptions.selection;
            let values = selectionsArray.map((a) => { return a.value; });
            if (values && values.length > 0)
                {
                    this.sendLanguage.emit(values);
                }
            else if (values && values.length < 1)
                {
                    this.sendLanguage.emit(this.obj = undefined);
                }
        }
}
```